# Does <include> comment tag suppress intellisense?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation, intellisense

I was playing around with the idea of using Visual Studio's [< include >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h8dy30z.aspx) tag to store some or all my code documentation separately from it's source, but when I tried creating a test xml file and pointed at it using the include for some of my methods, I discovered that intellisense didn't work for those methods.

Is the include tag for xml comments supposed to support intellisense, or is it not supported (for what I assume would be reasons of practicality)?  If it is supported, then what might I be doing wrong?  I'm pretty sure that my XPath is well formed, since StyleCop wasn't complaining about it.

I'm using VS2008, and I recently installed Resharper, StyleCop and StyleCop for Resharper.

Comment: Did you compile with: /doc:DocFileName.xml ?

Comment: According to the documentation, that option sets the output file for an automatically generated file that reflects all the XML documentation (including the stuff directly in the source file).  It's used for things like Sandcastle to generate help files.  The include tag is to import a user-specified file, which is also included in the output file specified by that tag.  What I need to know is if there is any way to make that information also show up in intellisense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not supported neither in V2008 nor in VS2010 :(

I'm not sure about particular reason, but most likely because there weren't enough requests to implement it from customers both internally and externally of Microsoft.

We might consider implementing it in VS.next though. It would help if you file it as a bug on Microsoft Connect (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) - then (provided there is a real demand for this feature) people would vote for it creating a pressure on Microsoft to implement it.

Comment: All right, I was afraid this would be the case, but it's good to know for certain.  Thanks!