# Visual Studio XML external comments file does not work

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, include, documentation

By using **include** tag I am trying to put comments for my code in separate file "docs.xml".
But it does not work. I have been trying both C# and VB.NET projects.

Here is my comments file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<d>
<summary>Demo summary</summary>
</d>
```

I have a class ABC with one single property Demo. before this property I write:

```
/// <include file="docs.xml" path="d/*" />
```

or in VB.NET:

```
''' <include file="docs.xml" path="d/*" />
```

However summary for ABC.Demo never appears in InteliSense / Object browser / another project (if I reference my project).

I have a strong feeling I am missing something here.

P.S. I have tried following "path[@name=]" pattern of XML file, but it does not help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does <include> comment tag suppress intellisense?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215100/does-include-comment-tag-suppress-intellisense)

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Tried 2010, 2012, 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you already saw this in the documentation then, but if I understand correctly, you have to do the following:

> In Visual Studio, you **specify** the XML doc comments option in the **Build
>   pane of the Project Designer.** When the C# compiler sees the 
>   tag, it will search for documentation comments in xml_include_tag.doc
>   instead of the current source file.